# Add target blank JQuery

Tags: jquery

In a search bar, I'm trying to make an URL open in a new window through JQuery.

This is my code from the search bar
And my JQuery code that makes the info you write on the search bar open in an URL with certain parameters added:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Initialize events
  $('#search-bar-button').click(function() {
    window.location.href = "https://www.amazon.es/s?k=" + $('#search-bar-text').val() + "&" + $('#tag-amazon').val(); // = document.getElementById("search-bar-text").value --- $('#parrafo').html()

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>

<div class="buscador">
  <div class="buscador-bar">
    <input type="hidden" id="tag-amazon" value="<?php echo $tagafiliadoEs ?>">
    <input oninput="textoinput()" type="text" id="search-bar-text" name="buscar" placeholder="¿Qué es lo que necesitas?" aria-label="Search" value=""><button id="search-bar-button" href="#" class="btn lupa"><i class="fas fa-search"></i>

</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the web: antenas.me

Comment: Use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) instead of `window.location`

Comment: How would you do add the parameters as well?

Comment: Exactly as you already are - by using concatenation. Just pass that string as an argument to `window.open()`